# Modal form tab navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is a link to see example.
http://atozcognac.com/hotel/form/# 
My prev and next buttons work but I can't figure out how to change tabs as well if user press prev or next.
Thank you for your time.
$(document).ready(function(){

```
//When someone clicks on the navigation links
$('.nav li').click(function(e){
    $('.nav li').attr('id', ''); //make all navtabs inactive
    $(this).attr('id', 'activetab'); //make the one we clicked active

    //hide all of the fieldsets
    $('fieldset').attr('class', 'myHidden');

    whichitem=$(this).attr('title'); //get the title of the nav we clicked

    //make the class of what we cleared not hidden
    $("fieldset[title='"+whichitem+"']").attr('class', ''); 
});


//When someone clicks on the previous button
$('.prev').click(function(e){
    var listItem = document.getElementById('activetab'); //find out which navtab is active
    whichOne=$('li').index(listItem); //get the index of the navtab

    $('.nav li').attr('id', ''); //make all the navtabs inactive
    $(".nav li:eq("+(whichOne-1)+")").attr('id', 'activetab'); //make previous tab active

    $('fieldset').attr('class', 'myHidden'); //hide all the fieldsets
    $("fieldset:eq("+(whichOne-1)+")").attr('class', ''); //show the previous fieldset
});


//When someone clicks on the next button
$('.next').click(function(e){
    var listItem = document.getElementById('activetab'); //find out which navtab is active
    whichOne=$('li').index(listItem); //get the index of the navtab

    $('.nav li').attr('id', ''); //make all the navtabs inactive
    $(".nav li:eq("+(whichOne+1)+")").attr('id', 'activetab'); //make next tab active

    $('fieldset').attr('class', 'myHidden'); //hide all the fieldsets
    $("fieldset:eq("+(whichOne+1)+")").attr('class', ''); //show the next fieldset
});
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the click event and use the logic you've already implemented in the click listener. And I would use a class `activetab` instead of an id.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//When someone clicks on the navigation links
$('.nav li').click(function(e){
    $('.nav li').removeClass("activetab"); //make all navtabs inactive
    $(this).addClass("activetab"); //make the one we clicked active

    //hide all of the fieldsets
    $('fieldset').addClass("myHidden");

    var whichitem=$(this).attr('title'); //get the title of the nav we clicked

    //make the class of what we cleared not hidden
    $("fieldset[title='"+whichitem+"']").removeClass("myHidden");
});


//When someone clicks on the previous button
$('.prev').click(function(e){
    // trigger the click
    $(".activetab").prev().click();
});


//When someone clicks on the next button
$('.next').click(function(e){
    // trigger the click
    $(".activetab").next().click();
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply for some reason still don't work for me.